# Fatal Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

In my app I send some string and make every first letter word Capital and it's working fine but for some users this method causing app crash. I can't figure out what causing crash, please help me below is my details.

**Error**

```
Thread-1891
       at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:1220)
       at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2013)
       at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:510)
       at jd.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280046@13.2.80 (040306-211705629):8)
       at jd.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_adsdynamite@13280046@13.2.80 (040306-211705629):64)
```

**Code where error occurs**

```
   public static String capitalize(@NonNull String input) {

        String[] words = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String word = words[i];

            if (i > 0 && word.length() > 0) {
                builder.append(" ");
            }

            String cap = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1); //This is the line causing app crash

            builder.append(cap);
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=1
       at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:298)
       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1087)
       at com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin.UserFragment.capitalize(UserFragment.java:64)
       at com.cbcwebs.app.wincoin.UserFragment$1.onDataChange(UserFragment.java:89)
       at com.google.firebase.database.zzp.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzfc.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzgx.zzdr(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_database.zzhd.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: while you are trying to capitalize the first character of the word by `word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)` , you should make sure that length of word>1 or else you'll get this error

Comment: @Deadpool  updated question please check now

Comment: try my answer @sam999

Comment: I know this is the equivalent of suggesting jQuery, but consider using WordUtils from Apache Commons. Check the capitalizeFully method here: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String- . It's a lightweight library and you won't notice an increase in apk size, especially if you use proguard.

Comment: updated code with java 8 you can try @sam999

Answer (score 5):

This line is causing app crash because there might be a case that word length is 1 and you are accessing 2nd char of word like this `word.substring(1)`.

Here is the corrected code

```
if(word.length() > 1)
String cap = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1); 
else
String cap = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: when there is single character else condition would be invoked